# Continuous extension in the proof of Arzela - Ascoli theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, uniform-convergence, uniform-continuity, equicontinuity, arzela-ascoli

I'm reading a proof of Arzela - Ascoli theorem (complex analysis version) and I've come to the part where we want to extend a function that is defined on one set to the closure of that set. The problem is that it's stated that "*the function is continuous on every compact set in our domain, therefore we can extend it continuously on the closure*" (our domain is open and connected set in $\mathbb{C}$). I'm quite sure that the idea should be to prove uniform continuity on the whole set and then extend it, and this is a bit harder.

Definitions:

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{C}$ be an open and connected set.

- Family of functions $ \mathfrak{F}=\{f_i : \Omega \to \mathbb{C} | i\in I\}$ is normal iff for every sequence $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in $\mathfrak{F}$ there is a subsequence $(f_{n_k})_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ and there is $f\in \mathfrak{F}$ such that for every compact $K\subset \Omega$, $(f_{n_k})$ converges to $f$ uniformly on $K$.
- Family of functions $ \mathfrak{F}=\{f_i : \Omega \to \mathbb{C} | i\in I\}$ is equicontinuous on $\Omega$ iff $(\forall z_0 \in \Omega)(\forall \epsilon >0)(\exists \delta >0)(\forall f \in \mathfrak{F})(\forall z\in \Omega)(|z-z_0|<\delta \implies |f(z)-f(z_0)|<\epsilon)$

Note that equicontinuity is sometimes (always?) defined as property in which $\delta$ in the expression above is independent from $z_0$. On compact sets these statements are equivalent.

Theorem: Let $ \mathfrak{F}$ be an equicontinuous family on $\Omega$. If $(\forall z\in \Omega) (\{f(z) | f \in \mathfrak{F}\}$ is sequentially compact), then $ \mathfrak{F}$ is a normal family.

Proof of the theorem starts by introducing $\Omega_1 =  \{x+iy | x,y \in \mathbb{Q}, x+iy \in \Omega\}$.
$\Omega_1$ is dense in $\Omega$ and countable. Since it's countable, it can be written as $\Omega_1=\{z_n|n\in \mathbb{N}\}$.

Then we take a sequence $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in $\mathfrak{F}$ and we want to make $f\in \mathfrak{F}$ and $(f_{n_k})_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ that converges to $f$ on compacts in $\Omega$.

We take $z_1\in \Omega_1$. $\{f(z_1) | f \in \mathfrak{F}\}$ is sequentially compact, so we have a convergent subsequence $(f_{n_k}(z_1))_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$. For first element of our subsequence we take $f_{n_1}$. Then we observe $(f_{n_k}(z_2))_{k \geq 2}$ and repeat the process etc.

We define $f:\Omega_1 \to \mathbb{C}$, $f(z_j)=lim_{k \to \infty}f_{n_k}(z_j)$.
We want $f$ to be defined on $\Omega$ and this is where the problem is. For $z,w \in \Omega_1$
$|f(z)-f(w)|\leq |f(z)-f_{n_k}(z)|+|f_{n_k}(z)-f_{n_k}(w)|+|f_{n_k}(w)-f(w)|$.

At this point we somehow start observing all of this on a compact set. I don't know what to do with this.

**Edit**: the reason why we observe this on a compact set is because we want to prove that $f$ is continuous on every compact set and therefore on $\Omega_1$ and this can be done. However, this doesn't guarantee the existence of the continuous extension. For that we need uniform continuity on the whole domain.